# hide lock button on sale order form based on state & condition in odoo10

Tags: python, xml, xpath, odoo-10

I'am using Odoo10 community, and I'am trying to inherit the sale order form and edit lock button, to make it visible only where state = sale and my own condition (based on an other field value `('Costum_field','=', 'Value1')`).

The originale code from sale module :

```
<button name="action_done" type="object" string="Lock" states="sale"
    help="If the sale is locked, you can not modify it anymore. However, you will still be able to invoice or deliver."/>
<field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,sent,sale"/>
```

This is my code :

```
<field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form" />
<field name="arch" type="xml">


    <xpath expr="//button[@name='action_done']" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="states" /> <!-- delete states attribute, it's influencing invisible behaviour -->
        <attribute name="invisible">['|' , ('state','!=', 'sale'), ('Costum_field','=', 'Value1')]</attribute>
    </xpath>

</field>
```

Now the button is invisble whatever the value of state and my costume field

Thank an advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to set conditional dynamic attributes on fields, buttons or other form elements you should rely on `attrs` field's attribute

> ```
> <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form" />
> <field name="arch" type="xml">
>     <xpath expr="//button[@name='action_done']" position="attributes">
>         <attribute name="states" /> <!-- delete states attribute, it's influencing invisible behaviour -->
>         <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': ['|' , ('state','!=', 'sale'), ('Costum_field','=', 'Value1')]}</attribute>
>     </xpath>
> </field>
> ```

Look [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/views.html#semantic-components)